# drupal watchdog filter the entries in the database

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-6, watchdog

On drupal 6 can i filter the entries of the watchdog into the database depending on the severity?

For example i want to exclude the "error" severity messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control what is written to the watchdog table through Drupal's UI, but you can filter which messages are displayed on the Recent Log Entries (/admin/reports/dblog) using the Filter Log Messages form within the collapsed fieldset at the top of the page (expand the fieldset, CTR+Click each of the severity levels you want displayed and click on the filter button.

If you really want to stop PHP errors from being written to the watchdog table, you can override your server's error_reporting (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) setting.

You can do this by, for example, placing a new directive in your settings.php file. Add this line to the bottom of settings.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```